# Syncing a table between two PostgreSQL databases consistently

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have 2 databases: postgres (new) ; tnpm (old). Currently, I need to copy data from [tnpm] to [postgres]. I am able to copy it using:

```
   INSERT INTO ip_cpu_mn(datetime, resource_name, cpu_utilization)

   SELECT cpu_mn.datetime,resource_name, cpu_utilization
   FROM dblink('host=10.0.32.175 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=TNPM_EXT',
 'SELECT datetime, resource_name, cpu_utilization
   FROM ext_ip.cpu_mn WHERE datetime =(SELECT MAX (datetime) - interval ''10 minutes'' as maxdate FROM ext_ip.cpu_mn)')

AS cpu_mn( datetime timestamp without time zone,
  resource_name character varying(150),
  cpu_utilization numeric(6,2))
```

Weirdly, when I start to verify between these database, the data is inconsistent in new database, seem it loss. The copy process is running using crontab 5 min. How can I avoid this ?

[image]

Comment: Don't try to home-brew this. Use a well established tool like Londiste that will get it right.

Comment: Do you really need to _copy_ the data? Can't you use a foreign data wrapper in the new database to access the table directly in the old database?

Answer (score 9):

Don't try to do replication yourself, it is a hard problem.  PostgreSQL has [a number of different replication schemes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication%2C_Clustering%2C_and_Connection_Pooling), several are built in.  All will be better than what you're doing.

What you're doing is creating a "hot standby" where copies of the database can be used for read-only queries.  [Here are instructions to set that up](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hot_Standby) and [detailed documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html).